# How to send user all details on email after user are update account in Drupal 7

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7

Currently,I want to send user all details on email after user are update account in Drupal 7.

I was able to successfully send user other details but i was not able to send password.

I am send all detail using drupal rule and action.I was trying to add [user:password] on a body but still, password gets blank.

I have send all detail like that :

[image]

```
Your Updated Name : [account:name]
Your unique id : [account:uid]
Your Roles : [account:roles]
Your Password is  [account:password]
```

Please suggest me what I write on a body for password.

If i should never send a password with email and if it's not possible than may i send link for reset their password.

I would like to know how could we do that in such a way that everybody will receive an email with their new password - or an email to reset their password.

Let me know which one is possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my question answer and it's successfully work.
Now I have successfully send link for reset password to user.

- Install [Mass Password Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/mass_pwreset) module and activate module.
- Then open people and click on MASS PASSWORD RESET and on Notify users
  of password reset via email
- Then Reset Passwords like below screenshot

[image]

For more details : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KpVa9Luzq8

Answer (score 2):

You can't get password from database since it's not stored as plain value. Instead, password is hashed (converted to some hash code) and that's one way operation. You can't get password back from that hash string.

Also, it's not very wise to send password in email because of security risks.

However, you may be able to get password (and send it) if user just changed the password (submitted the form that contains password value). If that's really what you want to do try creating form handler for user update form. Then hook it, so your form handler will be called and you can get submitted data, including password and send email from there.

Code should look something like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form().
 */
function mymodule_form_page_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) { 
    $form['buttons']['Change a taxonomy value and save'] = Array (
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Change a taxonomy value and save'),
        '#weight' => 4,
        '#submit' => Array('_mymodule_change_page_taxonomy_value_submit', 'node_form_submit')
    );
}

/**
 * Function to perform changes to the taxonomy field before page is saved
 */
function _mymodule_change_page_taxonomy_value_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
    // Change the taxonomy value to whatever it is meant to be
    $mynewtaxonomyvalue = [taxonomyobjectfromsomewhere]; 
    $form_state['values']['taxonomy'][5] = $mynewtaxonomyvalue->tid;
}
```

Copied example from here: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2010-01-29/adding-custom-submit-handlers-to-a#comment-3873354

But first check, maybe that password token is also available when user changes the password with rules, so you don't have to code.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal by default doesn't create a password when a new account is created hence you cannot send a password with the registration email, but you can send a one time link which allows the user to "activate" their account and to set their password.

In this case, your one-time-url token is: [user:one-time-login-url]

Comment: Thanks for replay @marameo, can we send that link multiple time for change password ?

Comment: Hi @patel, you might want to look at https://www.drupal.org/project/recovery_pass

Comment: This answer is correct; `[user:one-time-login-url]` is added in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_mail_tokens/7.x